# Android: Make LazyLoading ListView from GSON available without internet

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-listview, gson

I've just implemented GSON to Fedor's LazyLoading ListView. That means the app saves the downloaded images and texts from the web to the external storage though an ImageLoader class.

and I wonder why how to make this listview accessible without an internet connection.
Here I give you a snippet of my ListView Class:

```
public class ProjectsList extends Activity {
    ListView lstTest;

    ProjectAdapter arrayAdapter;

    ArrayList<Project> prjcts=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.projects_list);

        //Initialize ListView
        lstTest= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText);

        prjcts = new ArrayList<Project>();

        arrayAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectsList.this, R.layout.listitems,prjcts,ProjectsList.this);

            lstTest.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            if (isOnline())
            {
        WebService webService = new WebService("http://liebenwald.spendino.net/admanager/dev/android/projects.json");

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("var", "");

        String response = webService.webGet("", params);

        try
        {
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Project>>(){}.getType();
            List<Project> lst= new Gson().fromJson(response, collectionType);


            for(Project l : lst)
            {
                prjcts.add(l);
                ConstantData.projectsList.add(l);
            }

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
       }


        lstTest.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                Intent care = new Intent(ProjectsList.this, ProjectDetail.class);
                care.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);
                startActivity(care);
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        yAdapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
        lstTest.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
                 }
             });
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Please advise if more of my codes are required.
Thanks

Comment: Just write your code here `catch(Exception e)
        {
//Your Code,,,,,,,        }`

Comment: where should I write that? inside the onCreate?

Comment: Yes ,inside the `OnCreate`..When you are not getting any response from your web server..Just do what you want to do..

Comment: I know, that's why I implemented the isOnline method, but the thing is I want the List to show the cached image and text. With the code I'm having right now, when no internet is detected the listview just shows me a black black screen.

Comment: Are you being able to retrieve data from sqlite database and turn into them `Project` class?

Comment: I have used GSON, in order to do what I want, do I need to make sqlite database as well? What makes me wondering is, on Fedor's LazyList once there's no internet connection, it fetches the cached data automatically from the SD Card..but why it's not working the same on mine? I implemented his ImageLoader class to my app, what's difference only I'm using JSON as the source of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you need to have the data in your application so that you can call them when no internet connection is available...

When you are getting the data save it somewhere in your application.Then pass the data in your `Adapter`..

The images will not be downloaded again...

In Fedor's lazylist the url of the images  are static but here they are coming dynamically.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: interesting, can you guide me in doing this? Sorry for being demanding, but I'm quite a newbie in this

Comment: This link can help you http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=624&source=hp&q=android+sqlite+tutorial&aq=1&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=5104fce57ec41299